# Services in CentOS 7 Docker image without systemd

Tags: docker, shiny, rstudio, centos7, systemd

I'm trying to create a Docker container based on CentOS 7 that will host R, shiny-server, and rstudio-server, but to I need to have systemd in order for the services to start. I can use the systemd enabled centos image as a basis, but then I need to run the container in privileged mode and allow access to /sys/fs/cgroup on the host. I might be able to tolerate the less secure situation, but then I'm not able to share the container with users running Docker on Windows or Mac.

I found this question but it is 2 years old and doesn't seem to have any resolution.

Any tips or alternatives are appreciated.

UPDATE:  SUCCESS!

Here's what I found: For shiny-server, I only needed to execute `shiny-server` with the appropriate parameters from the command line. I captured the appropriate call into a script file and call that using the final CMD line in my Dockerfile.

rstudio-server was more tricky.  First, I needed to install initscripts to get the dependencies in place so that some of the rstudio scripts would work.  After this, executing `rstudio-server start` would essentially do nothing and provide no error.  I traced the call through the various links and found myself in /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rstudio-server.  The daemonCmd() function tests  cat /proc/1/comm to determine how to start the server.  For some reason it was failing, but looking at the script, it seems clear that it needs to execute `/etc/init.d/rstudio-server start`.  If I do that manually or in a Docker CMD line, it seems to work.

I've taken those two CMD line requirements and put them into an sh script that gets called from a CMD line in the Dockerfile.

A bit of a hack, but not bad.  I'm happy to hear any other suggestions.

Comment: _why_ do you need systemd, specifically?

Comment: shiny-server and rstudio-server require systemd in order to enable and start the services upon installation.  Is there a way for me to start services of this sort in the absence of systemd?  I tried init but it seemed to have other systemd dependencies that I couldn't work around.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use an init system like systemd.

Essentially, you need to start multiple services, there are existing patterns for this. Check out this page about how to use supervisord to achieve the same thing: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/